# I have to delete some stuff from /boot to make updates

Tags: updates, uninstall, aptitude

When i do my updates, the `/boot` folder is always full with old stuff...
So, after a while, I can't make any updates/upgrades anymore, because the `/boot` folder is full.
I have to delete some stuff from `/boot` via `sudo aptitude remove ...`
[image: my /boot directory]

I also have to remove from time to time my old headers and images...
[image: all headers and images installed]

Is that normal? My colleague, also with an Ubuntu does not have this problem

my `du -h boot` says:

```
3,4M    /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu
3,4M    /boot/efi/EFI
3,4M    /boot/efi
127K    /boot/grub/locale
2,4M    /boot/grub/fonts
2,9M    /boot/grub/x86_64-efi
7,7M    /boot/grub
12K /boot/lost+found
100M    /boot
```

Comment: How big is your /boot partition? It may well be you're a bit short on room, it doesn't usually come to a large amount of data, and is normally a smallish partition as well. Try running `du -h /boot` from command-line & editing this into the question...

Comment: to all the people marked it as duplicate: I'm not asking how to delete them, I ask if this is normal, or if there is some way to fix it, that it's automatically done. my colleagaue does not have this problem  .
@MarkWilliams - i edited the question

Comment: 100 MB is very small for `/boot`. The best course of action is to merge it with `/` or at least extend it to something like 500 MB (this is covered by some answers to the linked question). Imho these days there's no real reason to keep it on a separate file system from `/` unless you use a device mapping for the latter that is inaccessible to the early boot stages of Grub.

Answer (score 0):

It often depends on whether you have a separate `/boot` partition, if you're running out of space in that partition, you'll need to clear old kernel files to make room for the new ones. The recommended way to do this is to use:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This should leave you with your current kernel, and the previous one as a fallback. I tend to do this after running an update and successfully rebooting.

Comment: no, this make only some space available... but too less